# How to import existing C/C++ code into Eclipse?

Tags: android, c++, c, eclipse

I want to view some mixed C/C++/Java code (specifically the source of Android OS) that I have on my filesystem.

I could not find an option for "new C/C++ project" nor an option to create a project from existing files, unless it's from the source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret was to create a Java project and make sure the ‘Project name’ is the same as the folder name, which is where the files are:

http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/importing-existing-source-code-into-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

You need import the C/C++ project first(the same way you import jave project) .Then convert it to C/C++ project.